# Handling dynamic DB Connections in REST based website

Tags: java, rest, playframework

I am building a java REST APIs based website whose function is to connect to any user entered database and get the schemas, tables, indexes etc and the user can pick whatever schemas / tables / indexes they want and send to another system.

So the site takes the database details, then shows the schemas - user selects the schemas they need- then the site brings back the corresponding tables etc. So in the backend I have separate calls for getting schema/tables/indexes.

I am using plain JDBC calls in the server to do this. Each time I am opening the connection, getting the metadata(schema/table/index), closing the connection. I think performance can be improved if I keep the database connection open between requests.

Since the database details are dynamic and each user is connecting to a different database,I cannot use the connection pool facility provided in the (play) framework. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

I am using play framework 2.x with Angular JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a singleton or static Map of JDBC DataSource  and get the connexion from it. The datasource will manage the connexion pull.